# Deploying Java .war app to Heroku

Tags: java, deployment, heroku, war

Do you know any tutorial about deploying java war app to Heroku or is it possible?

Thanks...

Comment: Which app server do you want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Heroku you can run anything.  So you need to bring your own app server.  The recommended way to do this is to specify it as a dependency in your build descriptor.  Then upload your app and build descriptor so Heroku can assemble everything (dependencies and all).  But ultimately it's up to you how you get that stuff to Heroku.

Answer (score 13):

Actually sometimes using Google doesn't actually help that much.  Deploying Java war's on heroku is a pain and the steps outlined aren't that great.

Basically heroku runs only plain java processes so you need to wrap your war file around a main java file.  This blog article [Deploy war on Heroku](http://ollivander.franzoni.eu/2011/10/20/deploy-any-java-webapp-via-war-to-heroku/) outlines some of the steps and you also need to refer to [heroku's documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java) to actually figure out the final push to heroku from git.

Here are the steps you need to follow (I'm assuming you have a war file that's ready to go).

1. You need to build your jar file from your war file so that it has Jetty embedded into it and it's a runnable jar file so to speak.  This is done in step 2.
2. Create your maven app assembler target in your pom.xml.  There is an example snippet covered in the blog article and also in various other parts on the web.  Let's say this is called mywebapp.jar. (it must be a jar)
3. Now you have a war file and you need to create a main program that loads this war file and creates a jetty process.  Remember heroku can only run java processes so you are calling jetty as a straight process here.  Look at the blog article for an example - call this StartWebApp.java for example.
4. Heroku requires a simple procfile that is pretty much boilerplate. For example:

> web: sh target/bin/webapp

Upload everything onto a git repository so that you can easily push to heroku - use this directory structure:

```
pom.xml
Procfile
src/main/java/root - StartWebApp.java
src/main/resources - mywebapp.jar
```

Boom after this push to heroku (assuming you have a cedar stack all set up as outlined in the link to heroku above).

```
git push heroku master
```

Happy herokuing.  Also as you can tell this is ridiculously too much for deploying a war.  If you use heroku (as a paid customer) please submit a feature request to make this better.  Creating a runner class for your platform is a big no no.

Answer (score 3):

You can follow [this post](http://jufeappdev.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/custom-spring-mvc-web-app-in-heroku.html) from my blog, where there is a step by step explanation if you want to deploy the WAR file from your Spring MVC Web App. I wrote it after trying and getting my own app up and running on Heroku.